# Remove unexplainable img margin/space (CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, margin

I have some unexplainable image margin/Space below img when including images in my wordpress theme. You can see it here: http://www.wlanradios.net/logitech-squeezebox-radio/

See the Amazon logo image inside the content or scroll down and have a look in the "Ähnliche WLAN Radios" sidebar widget with the small thumbnails. The images seem to have a little margin-bottom / Space below it I can not get rid off. I discovered the html/css with firebug but don't get the it where this margins comes from. I in fact tried to

```
img {
margin:0!important;
padding:0!important;
border:0!important;
}
```

to overwrite every possible causes for the margin, with no success.

Where is the margin coming from and how to remove it?

Comment: Is there any specifier with more selectors? e.g. `img.class#id` ? Then a overwrite is possible.

Comment: Certainly the margin is from a parent element and not the img itself.

Comment: I could use aditional class, but I although tried it with an element style `<img style="margin:0!important; pading:0!important" >` with no success. 

Do you see the margin below at the bottom of the images I am talking about? This is very curious, as there is nothing in the css what could case this?!

Comment: @aldux it is more a space below the img element and following elements. If I discover it in firebug, I don't see the highlightet margin.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just put to those imgs :

```
display: block;
```

UPDATE:

Some explanations: *`img` is an inline element, so it has to deal with white-space, line-height, etc., as all inline elements. I guess the space you're seeing is actually caused by the line-height. So another solution if you want to keep your `img` as inline elements is to set its parent `line-height: 0;`.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: vertical-align: middle

Answer (score 1):

I have Deeply inspected the Issue, its a bit of haystick needle kind of thing.

1) **Amazon Image box** - Issue is with the **td** tag which creates a all sides padding of **6.71667px** , This is FORCEFULLY created by the td,th **padding which is set to 0.5em**

```
 th, td {
        border-spacing: 3px;
      //Tweak this Padding of 0.5em and you should destroy Amazon Extra Space
            padding: 0.5em;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
            }
```

You should be able to find and edit from *line 183* of the above css theme from **wp-content/themes/ar2-2-b-2-fixed/styles.css**

2) Coming to the second issue with WLAN Radios Pic , This image is pushed in due to the DIV tags Padding all set to 4px which is acting on the WLAN Radio pics.

Here are the Issue Pics:

[image: Ähnliche WLAN Radios Sidebar 4px padding]
**Amazon Image Issue Solved Pic**
[image: Amazon Issue Solved Pic]

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your approach. But the problem was not related to the paddings (as they are desired and removing don't solve the problem). The space is related having the img not defined as block element like  enguerranws point out.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your line-height on the img elements, and set it to 1. You must have a line height > 1 on a parent element.

You can also change the display of those img to 'block' (to avoid line spacing).

Comment: Thanks - I tried `img {line-height: 1em!important;}` but had no success.

Comment: As I said, you should set to the img : display: block; It's working fine.